# Explicit slicing across a particular dimension

Tags: numpy, pytorch, tensor, numpy-ndarray

I've got a 3D tensor `x` (e.g 4x4x100). I want to obtain a subset of this by explicitly choosing elements across the last dimension. This would have been easy if I was choosing the same elements across last dimension (e.g. `x[:,:,30:50]` but I want to target different elements across that dimension using the 2D tensor `indices` which specifies the idx across third dimension. Is there an easy way to do this in numpy?

A simpler 2D example:

```
x = [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[10,20,30,40,50,60]]
indices = [1,3]
```

Let's say I want to grab two elements across third dimension of `x` starting from points specified by `indices`. So my desired output is:

```
[[2,3],[40,50]]
```

Update: I think I could use a combination of `take()` and `ravel_multi_index()` but some of the platforms that are inspired by numpy (like PyTorch) don't seem to have `ravel_multi_index` so I'm looking for alternative solutions

Comment: What does `indices` hold? Sample data?

Comment: No, it contains indices that I want to take from `x` along the third dimension

Comment: Can you add sample case data (input and expected output)?

Comment: Why is `indices` a 2D tensor? Shouldn't it be a 1D tensor, e.g., `[0, 1, 10, 33, 50, ...]`?

Comment: I added an example where I'm not even slicing and I simply want to extract those elements. Does it make it clearer?

Comment: Use a minimal **representative** sample data. So, something that needs slicing.

Comment: fair enough -- done

Comment: if `indices` is supposed to give the output in the nth dimension along those indeces wouldnt the output be `[[2,4],[20,40]]`

Answer (score 2):

Iterating over the `idx`, and collecting the slices is not a bad option if the number of 'rows' isn't too large (and the size of the sizes is relatively big).

```
In [55]: x = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6],[10,20,30,40,50,60]])                      
In [56]: idx = [1,3]                                                            
In [57]: np.array([x[j,i:i+2] for j,i in enumerate(idx)])                       
Out[57]: 
array([[ 2,  3],
       [40, 50]])
```

Joining the slices like this only works if they all are the same size.

An alternative is to collect the indices into an array, and do one indexing.

For example with a similar iteration:

```
idxs = np.array([np.arange(i,i+2) for i in idx])
```

But broadcasted addition may be better:

```
In [58]: idxs = np.array(idx)[:,None]+np.arange(2)                              
In [59]: idxs                                                                   
Out[59]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
In [60]: x[np.arange(2)[:,None], idxs]                                          
Out[60]: 
array([[ 2,  3],
       [40, 50]])
```

---

`ravel_multi_index` is not hard to replicate (if you don't need clipping etc):

```
In [65]: np.ravel_multi_index((np.arange(2)[:,None],idxs),x.shape)              
Out[65]: 
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 9, 10]])
In [66]: x.flat[_]                                                              
Out[66]: 
array([[ 2,  3],
       [40, 50]])
In [67]: np.arange(2)[:,None]*x.shape[1]+idxs                                   
Out[67]: 
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 9, 10]])
```

Answer (score 0):

along the 3D axis:

```
x = [x[:,i].narrow(2,index,2) for i,index in enumerate(indices)]
x = torch.stack(x,dim=1)
```

by enumerating you get the index of the axis and index from where you want to start slicing in one.

[narrow](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.narrow) gives you a zero-copy `length` long slice from a starting index `start` along a certain axis

you said you wanted:

```
dim = 2
start = index
length = 2
```

then you simply have to stack these tensors back to a single 3D.

This is the least work intensive thing i can think of for pytorch.

**EDIT**

if you just want different indices along different axis and `indices` is a 2D tensor you can do:

```
x = [x[:,i,index] for i,index in enumerate(indices)]
x = torch.stack(x,dim=1)
```

You really should have given a proper working example, making it unnecessarily confusing.

Comment: This works if you want the same indices for each `a,b` in `x[a,b,:]` but I want to have different indices for each element in the first two dimensions

Comment: how about this solution, didnt read you wanted `2` values starting from `index`

Comment: there is an edit if you already saw the answer, maybe this solution is more appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it in numpy, now clue about torch, though.

The following picks a slice of length n along the third dimension starting from points idx depending on the other two dimensions:

```
# example
a = np.arange(60).reshape(2, 3, 10)
idx = [(1,2,3),(4,3,2)]
n = 4

# build auxiliary 4D array where the last two dimensions represent
# a sliding n-window of the original last dimension
j,k,l = a.shape
s,t,u = a.strides
aux = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, (j,k,l-n+1,n), (s,t,u,u))

# pick desired offsets from sliding windows
aux[(*np.ogrid[:j, :k], idx)]
# array([[[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
#         [12, 13, 14, 15],
#         [23, 24, 25, 26]],

#        [[34, 35, 36, 37],
#         [43, 44, 45, 46],
#         [52, 53, 54, 55]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with below using broadcasting:

```py
x = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]]) 
i = np.array([1,5])
N = 2 # number of elements I want to extract along each dimension. Starting points specified in i

r = np.arange(x.shape[-1])
r = np.broadcast_to(r, x.shape)

ii = i[:, np.newaxis]
ii = np.broadcast_to(ii, x.shape)

mask = np.logical_and(r-ii>=0, r-ii<=N) 

output = x[mask].reshape(2,3)
```

Does this look alright?